# get_item_quantity() Error When Fetching Feed

Tags: rss, feed

I'm using this script in two places on the same page to output some RSS feeds:

```
<?php
    include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
    $rss = fetch_feed('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=BarackObama');
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(3);
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
?>
<?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<p class="alert">No activity to display.</p>'; ?>
<ul>
<?php
    if (!$maxitems == 0)
    foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php echo $item->get_title(); ?>
                <time datetime="<?php echo $item->get_local_date('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'); ?>" class="timestamp">
                    <?php echo $item->get_local_date('%A %d %b %H:%M'); ?>
                </time>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I'm manually setting the cache lifetime in my `functions.php` to two hours:

```
function filter_handler( $seconds ) {
    return 7200;
}
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', 'filter_handler' );
```

A few times a day, the feed breaks and displays this error instead:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Error::get_item_quantity() in /public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/home-page.php on line 100`

It seems WordPress' fetch of this Twitter feed occasionally fails, then the error is output for 2 hours until the cache is flushed.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because Twitter [stopped the API v1](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired). To get around `WP_Error` in your code:

```
// functions.php
function fetch_twitter()
{
    $rss = fetch_feed('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=BarackObama');

    if ( is_wp_error( $rss ) )
        return;

    // continue in your function
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(3);
}

// template
fetch_twitter();
```

Won’t help much in your case. Switch to the new API.

Comment: Difficult to test since the problem is intermittent. It's been happening for a while now, be surprised if Twitter's API is that flakey. Thanks for the code to handle the error, have included that.

Comment: Unfortunately this still blocks the rest of the page from rendering when there's an error. Any way to prevent this?

Comment: Wrap it in a function. I will make an update.

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct in assuming this won't work with API v1.1, since `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=BarackObama` returns an error due to not being authenticated via OAuth?

Comment: @AlecRust Yes, seems so.